# Google maps V2 if i change my api key in developer console in updated version what will happen to the previous version of my application on playstore

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Google maps V2 if i change my api key in developer console in updated version of my android application. what will happen to the previous version of my application on play store. means the previous key will automatically change or my previous version of application will stop to show maps

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to change the api key? Is there a reason you want to delete the old API key?

Comment: I create a release key it work fine and I upload my application but the release key don't work in debug mode on my device there fore i change my key again to debug and now when i create the release apk with that relase key now it does not work and not showing the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation to the number of API keys you can have for Google Maps: if you need one key for an older release, another for a debug key, and another for a new release key, then just create new keys.

Comment: thanks basically i was confused in the regenerating key

Answer (score 0):

Showing the Google Maps v2 on android only depends on the package name and the SHA-1 declared in the API key. 
If the package name of your updated version is the same of your previous one, than you can continue using the Google Maps API and the application will show your maps.

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have doubt in mind that in my previous version the key was different and in updates it different. can it still work fine on those devices which already installed my app because developer console says it will terminate the old key in 24 hours.

Comment: Does it have the same package name ? 
Normally for each Android Studio Project, the SHA1-key should be the same, only the package name could differ.