# Custom Google Maps API Key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-android-api-2

**STORY**:

Our company were using Google Maps API for the past couple of years. We had an old API key that we were using. Today the key got expired or deleted by an unknown entity and all our applications cannot load maps anymore. I have tried to get to the Project Manager through all the account we have for the company but haven't found the were the old API key was created. We cannot just update our apps with the new key as we cannot push any updates (legacy software).

**TLDR QUESTION:**

Can I contact Google in any way and ask them to reenable that key or grant our company account access to that key? Google doesn't seem to have a "developer support" phone number you can call in. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: dont you have the key in the source code of your apps?

Comment: @ihimv It's not about 'having' the key lol. I have it. But Google doesn't recognise it as a valid key anymore.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992184/google-maps-v2-if-i-change-my-api-key-in-developer-console-in-updated-version-wh